# Regex: whitepsace and &nbsp; in non-capturing group

Tags: regex, string, match

I am using a regex within PHP to match time strings. I would like to include both white space and `&nbsp;` in the non-capturing group to get the following matches:

Match: 10pm
Match: 10`&nbsp;`pm

This is the regex I'm using but it is not matching items with `&nbsp;`

```
(\b)(\d{1,2}:\d\d|\d{1,2})(?:\s|&nbsp;)(a\.?m\.?|p\.?m\.?)(\s|<|$|,)
```

Comment: I'm just going by JS but I believe in PHP `\s*` is the same. It is any whitespace - zero or more times or `[ ]*` maybe it's the same for PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[/\b\d{1,2}(?:\s*(?:&nbsp;)?\s*)?(?:[ap]m\b|[ap]\.m\.)/](https://regex101.com/r/9186yf/2)

```
/\b\d{1,2}(?:\s*(?:&nbsp;)?\s*)?(?:[ap]m\b|[ap]\.m\.)/
```

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary: `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`)

  - `{1,2}` matches the previous token between **1** and **2** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Non-capturing group `(?:\s*(?:&nbsp;)?\s*)?`

  - `?` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
    - `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    - Non-capturing group `(?:&nbsp;)?`

      - `?` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

        - `&nbsp;` matches the characters **&nbsp;** literally
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
    - `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Non-capturing group `(?:[ap]m\b|[ap]\.m\.)`

  - 1st Alternative `[ap]m\b`

    - Match a single character present in the list below `[ap]`

      - `ap` matches a single character in the list **ap**
    - `m` matches the character **m** literally
    - `\b` assert position at a word boundary: `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
  - 2nd Alternative `[ap]\.m\.`

    - Match a single character present in the list below `[ap]`

      - `ap` matches a single character in the list **ap**
    - `\.` matches the character **`.`** literally
    - `m` matches the character **m** literally
    - `\.` matches the character **`.`** literally
- Global pattern flags

  - `g` modifier: **g**lobal. All matches (don't return after first match)

```js
console.log(`
  Match10pm<br>
  Match:100pm<br>
  Match:10pm<br>          - match
  Match:10  pm<br>        - match
  Match:10 pmm<br>
  Match: 10p.m<br>
  Match: 10p.m.<br>       - match
  Match: 10 pm <br>       - match
  Match: 10&nbsp;pm       - match
  Match: 10&nbsp;pmm
  Match: 10&nbsp; pm<br>  - match
  Match: 10 &nbsp;pm<br>  - match
  Match: 10 &nbsp; pm<br> - match`
    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/9186yf/2]
    .match(/\b\d{1,2}(?:\s*(?:&nbsp;)?\s*)?(?:[ap]m\b|[ap]\.m\.)/g)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match both values, you could write and shorten the pattern to:

```
\b\d{1,2}(?::\d\d)?(?:\s?|&nbsp;)[ap]\.?m\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
- `(?::\d\d)?` Optionally match `:` and 1-2 digits
- `(?:\s?|&nbsp;)` Match an optional whitespace char or `&nbsp`
- `[ap]\.?m` match either `a` or `p` optional dot and `m`
- `\b` A word boundary or use `(?:\s|<|$|,)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nONDeB/1)